# Print line after the match in grep

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to get the current track running from 'cmus-remote -Q'
Its always underneath of this line

```
 tag genre Various
 <some track>
```

Now, I need to keep it simple because I want to add it to my i3 bar. I used

```
cmus-remote -Q | grep -A 1 "tag genre"
```

but that grep's the 'tag' line AND the line underneath.

I want ONLY the line underneath.

Comment: What about just excluding the RE with another pipe? `cmus-remote -Q | grep -A 1 "tag genre" | grep -v "tag genre"` ? It fails if the RE is on two lines in a row, of course.

Comment: If your `grep` supports `-P` option then it's so simple, `grep -oPz 'tag genre.*\n\K.*' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `grep` as the tool for this, you can achieve it by adding another segment to your pipeline:

```
cmus-remote -Q | grep -A 1 "tag genre" | grep -v "tag genre"
```

This will fail in cases where the string you're searching for is on two lines in a row. You'll have to define what behaviour you want in that case if we're going to program something sensible for it.

Another possibility would be to use a tool like `awk`, which allows for greater compexity in the line selection:

```
cmus-remote -Q | awk '/tag genre/ { getline; print }'
```

This searches for the string, then gets the next line, then prints it.

Another possibility would be to do this in bash alone:

```
while read line; do
  [[ $line =~ tag\ genre ]] && read line && echo "$line"
done < <(cmus-remote -Q)
```

This implements the same functionality as the awk script, only using no external tools at all. It's likely slower than the awk script.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/tag genre/{n;p}'
```

Output:

```
$ cmus-remote -Q | sed -n '/tag genre/{n;p}'
<some track>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` instead of `grep`:

```
awk 'p{print; p=0} /tag genre/{p=1}' file

<some track>
```

- `/tag genre/{p=1}` - sets a flag `p=1` when it encounters `tag genre` in a line.
- `p{print; p=0}` when `p` is non-zero then it prints a line and resets `p` to `0`.

Comment: Thanks , that works as well , but I think the grep -v , Is just easier :<

Comment: Hmm but that invokes 2 commands instead of just one with awk

Comment: Ok , fair enough :). Thanks

Comment: This solution also assumes that you only want to do this search once per file. I don't think that was a criterion on the question.

Comment: We can replace `exit` by `p=0` to get multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using awk:

```
awk 'seen && seen--; /tag genre/ { seen = 1 }'
```

- when `seen` is true, print the line.
- when `seen` is true, decrement the value, so it will no longer true after the desired number of lines are printed
- when the pattern matches, set `seen` to the number of lines to be printed